# Жук — этимология

Tags: этимология

Существуют ли в старославянском/русском ещё существительные, образованные путём присоединения к звукоподражательной основе этимологического (?) суффикса (?) -к, по аналогии с жу- + -к -> жук?

Comment: Что с вопросительными знаками внутри вопроса? Почему суффикс в кавычках?

Comment: @shampar сомнение в наименовании словообразовательного элемента

Comment: Вам такой шикарный ответ дали - лучше не дадут! Так отметьте ж его галочкой: полезен! В Ваши вопросы потому народ и не идёт, что как в пропасть падают ответы: ни оценки, ни признания.

Answer (score 4):

https://studbooks.net/2106590/literatura/zvukopodrazhaniya_russkom_yazyke :

> И в диахронии, и в синхронии регулярным и продуктивным является
>   использование суффикса *-k- (-к-). Древний аффикс оформляет как
>   глагольные, так и именные ономатопоэтические основы, но подвергается
>   фонетическим изменениям (палатализации, йотации) и переразложению
>   (рыкать, рычать, звучать, бык, жук, рык, грач, звук, брыкаться и т.
>   д.).В современном русском языке словообразовательная модель с
>   суффиксом глаголов -к- (мяукать, хрюкать, шушукать, хныкать, каркать,
>   крякать, квакать, рявкать, тявкать, хрумкать) также является
>   продуктивной.

ХРЯК тоже суффиксальное производное от звукоподражания хря, ср. хрюшка.
https://lexicography.online/etymology/%D1%85/%D1%85%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BA